# After installing 2011 SP1 HR 2, publish transaction gets stuck with status Throttled

Tags: 2011, publishing

I just installed 2011 SP1 Hotfix rollup #2, and republished a some of items. The first 3 were published OK, but then one got stuck in the publishing queue with status **Throttled**. Subsequent publish transactions are now stuck at status **Waiting for Publish**. Any ideas on what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From my experience I have seen this happen a lot when the `WindowSize` you configure in **cd_deployer_conf.xml** is larger than the `Workers`, also configured in **cd_deployer_conf.xml**.  Items get transported to the Deployer and are simply waiting to be deployed. But if mass publishing is going on you will see a lot of files in the Deployer's incoming directory waiting to be deployed and occasionally one transaction gets left behind as both the Transport service and the Deployer are busy with other deployments; *this is the extremely simplified explanation for this.*

In order to solve this I always recommend to have the `WindowSize` equal to the `Workers` to lessen the amount of waits for Publish Transactions. If you change this configuration, restart both the Deployer and the Transport service to propagate the new values.

Comment: @Bart Did anything change in HR2 that could affect this behaviour> From Will's question I gather the problem didn't exist before.

Comment: That seems to do the trick! Thanks Raimond

Comment: @Quirijn, I'm unaware of any changes there, but also not sure what the default setting are that might have been placed during the HR2 install or before

Comment: @Quirijn there have been some fixes in the way the transport service communicates with the deployer service. The whole mechanism works a lot better now - but is not quite there.

Answer (score 4):

I've had a similar issue once. In my case I fixed it with changing the **windowsize** inside the **meta.xml**. You can have a look at my blog post here:

http://stefanstridion.blogspot.com/2013/04/throttled-problem-when-publishing.html

Have in mind that I had the issue on Tridion 2013 but it seems to me that it could be the same as if it was 2011.

I hope this will be useful.

Comment: Please don't change the WindowSize in meta.xml. The value of the window size will get written upon deployer restart in meta.xml

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same and it was really weird when I saw that it actually did not change at all... I mention it inside my blog post. I agree that it was a very weird case.

Answer (score 3):

it's also worthwhile looking at your /bin/transactions folder as well as the incoming folder for your deployer. In HR2 the cms becomes much more sensitive to issues on the deployer side, so you may have a bunch of old transaction/zip files in those directories that would cause the 'Throttled' message to appear.

Comment: Thanks for this great tip.  We had the Throttled issue after we installed HR2 on our Tridion 2011 SP1 environment and restarted the deployer sites.  I was not able to resolve this issue.  There was nothing in the logfile, event view, ... and configuration was not changed so I had totally no idea where to look.  Until I found this comment.  After cleaning the incoming folder the publishing was working again.